# SQL Query: Is it possible to select or get the records of a Column that has the same values without any parameter to compare?

Tags: sql, vb.net

Is it possible to select or get the records of a Column that has the same values without any parameter to compare?

```
(Row1, Column1).Value = 5
(Row2, Column1).Value = 3
(Row3, Column1).Value = 5
(Row4, Column1).Value = 5
```

You may notice that **Row1** , **Row3** and **Row4** has the same values. I'd like to get the those records. **And NOTE: No parameters to compare like this one: SELECT * FROM Table WHERE Column1 = 5(*this is the parameter*)**

Im asking if is it possible without any parameter to compare.

Comment: You want it to get the records that have the same value on column1? It would probably be good if you explained a little better and maybe give the schemma to help figure it out.

Comment: Im new here, that means I am not able to post an Image.

Comment: Write the "create table" statement. and please expand a little on your requirement

Comment: Create Table SJF(
Process varchar(10),
BurstTime int);


I want to get the records that have the same values on BurstTime. (Without parameter to compare)

Comment: Does Joe's answer work for you? That will return all values that appear multiple times.

Comment: Ye it works! Finally! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like:

```
SELECT ... FROM ...
WHERE Column1 IN
(SELECT Column1 FROM Table
GROUP BY Column1 HAVING COUNT(*) > 1)
```